# Executing operations on a random sequence

Tags: geogebra

I have a random list of points and I would like to execute statement on it, If xPoint^2/2 - yPoint > 0, color that point red.

I have difficulty on executing that algorithm

```
L=Sequence((RandomBetween(-6,p),RandomBetween(-6,q)),i,1,100)
Sequence[If[ x(Element(L, i))^2/2^2 - y(Element(L, i)) >=0,SetColor(Element(L, counter),"Red")],i,1,50]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most GeoGebra commands are declarative, they define relationships between objects. Exception to that rule is scripting commands like `SetColor` that are imperative. It is not possible to call scripting `SetColor` from a declarative command like `Sequence`. However you can define the list of objects that you want to make red:

```
l2=KeepIf[ x(A)^2/2^2 - y(A) >=0, A, L]
```

and then you can make these objects red either from the UI or using `SetColor(l2,"red")`.

This way you end up with two lists where l2 covers some elements of l1. If it's a problem, you can define `l3=L\l2` and hide the original list `L`.

In the original question the second list only has 50 elements while L has 100, if it's intentional you can use `First(L,50)` as the last argument of `KeeepIf`.